# List of all instances created by a module

Tags: google-compute-engine, terraform

I have a number of module invocations that look similar to this

```
  1 module "gcpue4a1" {
  2   source = "../../../modules/pods"
  3
  4 }
```

where the module is creating instances, DNS records, etc.

```
locals {
  gateway_name = "gateway-${var.network_zone}-${var.environment}-1"
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "gateway" {
  name                      = "${local.gateway_name}"
  machine_type              = "n1-standard-8"
  zone                      = "${var.zone}"
  allow_stopping_for_update = true
}
```

How can I iterate over a list of all instances that have been created through this module. Can I do it with instance tags or labels?

In the end what I want is to be able to iterate over a list to export to an ansible inventory file. But I'm just not sure how I do this when my resources are encapsulated in modules.

With terraform show I can clearly see the structure of the variables.

```
➜  gcp-us-east4 git:(integration) ✗ terraform show | grep google_compute_instance.gateway -n1
640-  zone = us-east4-a
641:module.screencast-gcp-pod-gcpue4a1-food.google_compute_instance.gateway:
642-  id = gateway-gcpue4a1-food-1
--
--
991-  zone = us-east4-a
992:module.screencast-gcp-pod-gcpue4a2-food.google_compute_instance.gateway:
993-  id = gateway-gcpue4a2-food-1
--
--
1342-  zone = us-east4-a
1343:module.screencast-gcp-pod-gcpue4a3-food.google_compute_instance.gateway:
1344-  id = gateway-gcpue4a3-food-1
--
--
1693-  zone = us-east4-a
1694:module.screencast-gcp-pod-gcpue4a4-food.google_compute_instance.gateway:
1695-  id = gateway-gcpue4a4-food-1
```

The etcd inventory piece works just fine when I explicitly say which node I want. The overall inventory piece below it does not and I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
 10   ##Create ETCD Inventory
 11   provisioner "local-exec" {
 12     command =  "echo \"\n[etcd]\n${google_compute_instance.k8s-master.name} ansible_s    sh_host=${google_compute_instance.k8s-master.network_interface.0.address}\" >> kubesp    ray-inventory"
 13   }
 14
 15   ##Create Nodes Inventory
 16   provisioner "local-exec" {
 17     command =  "echo \"\n[kube-node]\" >> kubespray-inventory"
 18   }
 19 #  provisioner "local-exec" {
 20 #    command =  "echo \"${join("\n",formatlist("%s ansible_ssh_host=%s", google_compu    te_instance.gateway.*.name, google_compute_instance.gateway.*.network_interface.0.add    ress))}\" >> kubespray-inventory"
 21 #  }

➜  gcp-us-east4 git:(integration) ✗ terraform apply

Error: resource 'null_resource.ansible-provision' provisioner local-exec (#4): unknown resource 'google_compute_instance.gateway' referenced in variable google_compute_instance.gateway.*.id
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make sure each module adds a [label](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/labeling-resources#adding_or_updating_labels_to_existing_resources) that matches the module
and you can then use [gcloud compute instances list](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/list) and use a filter to only show the ones with the specific lablel.